RuntimeError: Placeholder storage has not been allocated on MPS device while fine-tuning model on MacBook Pro M2
I'm trying to create a proof of concept (PoC) for a local code assistant by fine-tuning the tiny_starcoder_py-vi06 model on my MacBook Pro with an M2 chip. My dataset looks like this:
[
  { "filename": "filename.ext", "text": "const a = 1; // other code" }
]

Here’s the code I’m using:
import torch
import pandas as pd
from datasets import Dataset
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, DataCollatorForLanguageModeling, Trainer, TrainingArguments

def main():
    model_name = "tiendung/tiny_starcoder_py-vi06"
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

    if tokenizer.pad_token is None:
        tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': tokenizer.eos_token})

    model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))

    df = pd.read_json("collection.json")
    dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(df)

    def tokenize_function(examples):
        return tokenizer(examples["text"], padding="max_length", truncation=True)

    tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
    tokenized_datasets.set_format(type='torch', columns=['input_ids', 'attention_mask'])

    data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False)

    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir="./results",
        overwrite_output_dir=True,
        num_train_epochs=3,
        per_device_train_batch_size=8,
        save_steps=10_000,
        save_total_limit=2,
    )

    device = torch.device("mps" if torch.backends.mps.is_available() else "cpu")
    model.to(device)

    def move_to_device(batch):
        batch['input_ids'] = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
        batch['attention_mask'] = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
        return batch

    tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.map(move_to_device, batched=True)

    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        data_collator=data_collator,
        train_dataset=tokenized_datasets,
    )

    trainer.train()
    trainer.save_model("fine_tuned_model")
    tokenizer.save_pretrained("fine_tuned_model")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Error Encountered:
When running the code, I get the following error:
RuntimeError: Placeholder storage has not been allocated on MPS device!
Questions:

Is there something I might have missed in the setup for using the MPS device?
Are there specific configurations or adjustments needed for training on MacBook's M2 chip?
Any recommendations for troubleshooting this issue?

Environment Details:

OS: macOS
Chip: Apple M2
Transformers version: 4.42.4

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

You could try using MLX LM. It will be faster and work well on macOS. Here's some documentation on LoRA fine-tuning https://github.com/ml-explore/mlx-examples/blob/main/llms/mlx_lm/LORA.md
